# Advise for camera buying

Tags: camera, computer-vision, camera-calibration

I am intending to buy a camera for my research about robotics. I am relatively new if I am ashamed to say that I am absolutely new to CV.
My job is detecting an objects and return the [x,y,z] coordinate. My platform is Ubuntu 12.04 and I intend to use python to program.
I read about some device on the internet like Kinect x360. But I have no ideas to choose the best one[price and suits my job (return x,y,z with precision < 5mm after caliberating, no entertainment needed)].

Please advice for the right one with suitable price or the best price.

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

With that few information about the problem I can just give you general advice.

The Kinect camera you mentioned not only captures images but can also give a rough estimation of the distance of every pixel from the camera. This can be very useful for determining the position of an object but I think you cannot obtain a 5mm precision with it.

I think your best bet is to go with two cameras and do [stereo vision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_stereo_vision) to obtain the distance. You can use normal cameras to do that but you'll need a high resolution to obtain the precision you want.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks very much. My question is asking about the branch of the camera that solve my problem (detecting  object and and returning the localizing the objects 3 D x,y,z. What is suitable one for it. I could know that somewhat expensive ones can solve it. But what i concern is price. That is I will solve my precision with some existing state-of-art techniques  or optimizing price and precision. I have no experience of choosing camera to buy. Please give me advice.

Comment: A brand that I worked with and does some good cameras for computer vision is [Point Grey](http://www.ptgrey.com/stereo-vision-cameras-systems), but they are not cheap.